# Error is thrown when trying to change brightness on a fabricjs canvas,

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

When running the changeBrightness function I get this error in Chrome:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filters' of undefined

```
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
fabric.Image.fromURL('fingerprints/1.bmp', function(img) {
    canvas.setHeight(500);
    canvas.setWidth(500);
    canvas.add(img);
    canvas.item(0).setControlVisible("mb", false).setControlVisible("mt",
            false).setControlVisible("mr", false).setControlVisible("ml",
            false);
    canvas.renderAll();
});
function changeBrightness(value) {
    var cimg = canvas.getActiveObject();
    cimg.filters.brightness = parseInt(value, 10);
    cimg.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message suggests, your `cimg` is `undefined`.

```
var cimg = canvas.getActiveObject();
```

Open up your console and make sure `canvas.getActiveObject()` actually returns an object.